# Dynamic transposing rows to columns using awk based on row value

Tags: linux, awk

I have file with data for data_0 to data_4 repeated in rows. I need to convert it into columns values under respected dataset. Is there any way to put blank/null value in case data is missing for earlier category. For Example

```
TimeStamp,Block,No_of_requests
04:19:12,data_0,4
04:19:12,data_1,6
04:19:12,date_2,8
04:19:12,date_3,10
04:19:12,data_4,12
04:19:14,data_0,5
04:19:14,data_1,6
04:19:14,date_3,7
04:19:14,data_4,8
```

Expected output is

```
TimeStamp,data_0,data_1,data_2,data_3,data_4
04:19:12,4,6,8,10,12
04:19:14,5,6,,7,8
```

etc. It should put empty data incase value for respective data_x is not available.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help for formatting help.. also add your research efforts to question..

Answer (score 3):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ 
         FS = OFS = ",";
         PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";
         print "TimeStamp,data_0,data_1,data_2,data_3,data_4" 
     }
     NR > 1{ a[$1][substr($2, 6) + 1] = $3 }
     END{ 
         for (i in a) { 
             printf "%s,", i;
             for (j=0; j<=4; j++) printf "%s%s", a[i][j+1], (j == 4? ORS:OFS) 
         }
     }' file
```

The output:

```
TimeStamp,data_0,data_1,data_2,data_3,data_4
04:19:12,4,6,8,10,12
04:19:14,5,6,,7,8
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Roman's answer, but hardcodes less about the contents of the file

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR > 1 {data[$1][$2] = $3; blocks[$2]}
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"

        # header
        printf "TimeStamp"
        for (block in blocks) {
            printf "%s%s", OFS, block
        }
        print ""

        # data
        for (ts in data) {
            printf "%s", ts
            for (block in blocks) {
                printf "%s%s", OFS, data[ts][block]
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
' file
```

```
TimeStamp,data_0,data_1,data_4,date_2,date_3
04:19:12,4,6,12,8,10
04:19:14,5,6,8,,7
```

Note that your sample data uses "**data**" and "**date**" both.